# Horizontal scrolling for some columns in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within a table I need to 'pin' a column in place and have other other colums horizontally scrollable. Here is a visual example:

[image]

I tried using overflow scroll but it appears to do nothing:

```
.horizontal-scrolling {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.horizontal-scrolling th {
  width: 250px;
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <span class="horizontal-scrolling">
                <th>Second</th>
                <th>Third</th>
                <th>Fourth</th>
            </span>
        </tr>
    <thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the w3schools standart table, to where one column sticks to the left. this kind of styling can be applied to a specific column of your table by javascript

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 1000px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
tr th:nth-of-type(1),/*this is where the table column gets its*/
tr td:nth-of-type(1){/*styling to stick to the left and stay ontop of the rest*/
position:sticky;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
background: white;
width: 150px
}
div {
width: 600px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: note this still needs some tweaking, the other columns are showing 1/2pixels on the left of the floating column when scrolling by